# limit of series about binomials

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

What is a value of following limit?
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left({\sum_{k=1}^{2n} \frac{1}{\binom{2n}{k}}}\right)^n$$
I don't know how do I approach.

Thanks to your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $n\geq3$. For $k\in\{3,4\ldots, 2n-3\}$ we have
$$\binom{2n}{k}\geq \binom{2n}{3}$$
Thus
$$\eqalign{0\leq \sum_{k=2}^{2n-2}\frac{1}{\binom{2n}{k}}&\leq \frac{2}{\binom{2n}{2}}+\frac{2n-5}{\binom{2n}{3}}.
}$$
Thus if $
A_n=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2n}\dfrac{1}{\binom{2n}{k}}
$,
then we conclude from
$$
A_n=1+\frac{2}{\binom{2n}{1}}+\sum_{k=2}^{2n-2}\frac{1}{\binom{2n}{k}}
$$
that
$
B_n{\buildrel{\rm def}\over{=}}n(A_n-1)
$, satisfies $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}B_n=1$. Now
$$
n\log(A_n)=B_n\frac{\log\left(1+\frac{B_n}{n}\right)}{\frac{B_n}{n}}
$$
So
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\log(A_n^n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}B_n\cdot\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log\left(1+\frac{B_n}{n}\right)}{\frac{B_n}{n}}=1
$$
Because $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}=1$. Finally, since $x\mapsto e^x$ is continuous we conclude that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}A_n^n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\exp(n\log(A_n))=e^1=e.$$

Comment: Can you give me a proof that don't use a big O notation?